# Parent Page refresh when child window close in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle, oracle-apex

i have make a interactive report with form
now the interactive report is the - page no- 2 - parent page
form page is the - page no 3- child page

in parent page i have written a java script to open a modal page(form page -page no3 )- link is

**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function MWindow(a,b)
 {
if (window.showModalDialog) 
{
window.showModalDialog
("f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&SESSION.:POP:NO::P3_KEY,P3_E_KEY:"+a+","+b+":","name","dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:400px");
}
else  
{
window.open("f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&SESSION.:POP:NO::P3_E_KEY:P5_ELEMENT_ID:","name","height=400,width=600,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes");
}
}
</script>
```

**

ON PAGE NO- 2
I HAVE GIVEN FOLLOWING LINKS
on create button -javascript function is calling - `javascript:MWindow(',&P5_ELEMENT_ID.');`
ON EDIT LINK - JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION IS CALLING- `javascript:MWindow(#R_KEY#,#R_ELMT_KEY#);`

now child page is opening and ON THAT i can create the RECORD and apply changes ON  the record (CREATE BUTTON AND APPLY CHANGES BUTTON)

in the process also i have created the process that when any changes happen the pop window close (Close popup window) event given .
all process is working

i want to know when popup window (page no 3)close , it must refresh the page of parent window (page no 2) - (UPDATED RECORD MUST SHOWN THERE)

Answer (score -1):

The close popup window event could execute this

```
$('#my_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
```

which would refresh the relevant report region with your new record